# Use notebook with slurm

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, slurm

I want to be able to connect to our institution's cluster using VS Code Remote SSH without the server running on a compute node instead of the login node. The preferred workflow is to SSH into the login node and then use a command to allocate a job and spin up an interactive shell on a compute node, and then run the jupyter notebook kernel on those node.

I launch jupyter-lab through this bash script

```sh
    #!/bin/bash
    #SBATCH -J jupyterTest
    #SBATCH -N 1
    #SBATCH --mem=16GB
    #SBATCH --time=5:00:00
    #SBATCH --output=/home/adufour/work/jupyter.log
    
    #Load necessary modules
    module purge
    
    source /home/adufour/.bashrc
    conda activate singlecell
    
    #Go to the folder you wanna run jupyter in
    cd ~/work
    
    #Start the notebook
    jupyter lab --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8888
```

Which give me the following log :

```
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:29.363 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.551 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.690 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /work/adufour/anaconda3/envs/singlecell/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jupyterlab
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.691 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /work/adufour/anaconda3/envs/singlecell/share/jupyter/lab
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.698 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.714 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.719 ServerApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /work/adufour
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.719 ServerApp] Jupyter Server 1.3.0 is running at:
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.719 ServerApp] http://node126:8888/lab?token=6a1178ff82901e42559423100b13ba12105935432fb0efdd
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.719 ServerApp]  or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=6a1178ff82901e42559423100b13ba12105935432fb0efdd
[I 2021-02-16 16:14:31.719 ServerApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 2021-02-16 16:14:31.744 ServerApp] 
    
    To access the server, open this file in a browser:
        file:///home/adufour/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jpserver-108627-open.html
    Or copy and paste one of these URLs:
        http://node126:8888/lab?token=6a1178ff82901e42559423100b13ba12105935432fb0efdd
     or http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab?token=6a1178ff82901e42559423100b13ba12105935432fb0efdd
Unable to connect to VS Code server.
Error in request
```

Comment: Hi @Goultard. Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please, clarify your question and tell us what exactly do you need.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question